# FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist ; Firebase Token Verification

Tags: java, maven, authentication, token, firebase-authentication

in order to verify a Firebase token sent from a client app i have the following code:

```
Task<FirebaseToken> authTask = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken("very long string token").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(Object tr) { }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
@Override
public void onFailure(Exception excptn) { }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
@Override
public void onComplete(Task task) { }
});
try {
Tasks.await(authTask);
} catch(ExecutionException | InterruptedException e ){
//handle error
}
FirebaseToken decodedToken = authTask.getResult();
String uid = decodedToken.getUid();
```

When deploy it through Maven/google backend api I get the following error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to set up a Service Account at your Google Cloud Console. Read the [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup).
2. Put the service account key file (.json) in your `/resources/META-INF/` directory.
3. Make sure you have included your resource files inside the `appengine-web.xml`

```
<!-- Include resource files -->
<resource-files>
    <include path="/**.json" />
    <include path="/**.xml" />
    <include path="/**.properties" />
</resource-files>
```

4. Pass over the `FirebaseOptions` with the generated `service_account_key.json` file to initialize `FirebaseApp`. You can do this inside a [Warmup Servlet](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/warmup-requests/).

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

    InputStream loadedServiceAccount = config
        .getServletContext()
        .getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/service_account_key.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setServiceAccount(loadedServiceAccount)
        .setDatabaseUrl("URL_FIREBASE_DATABASE").build();

    FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance(firebaseApp);

}
```

5. Then you can go on using `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` inside your code.

---

When your AppEngine Instance runs a beta Version (maybe 1.9.44) it will give you a noMethodFoundError. Then you can go on with this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39053087/firebase-in-google-app-engine-throwing-nomethodfound-error-while-initialization).