# Firebase in Google app engine throwing noMethodFound error while initialization

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, firebase

I am trying to initialize firebase in Google appengine web app and using maven for dependencies.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-server-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>[3.0.0,)</version>
    </dependency>
```

Getting error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.fromStream(....)
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder.setServiceAccount(FirebaseOptions.java:77)
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes, It was the dependency issue with other libraries in the project. I fixed it using the latest dependencies from firebase, google app engine and others.

Comment: Can you post the dependencies as an answer? I have the same issue. Would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How to solve this issue:

1. Go to  http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cgoogle-api-client and find the last version of com.google.api-client API.
2. Add the dependency on you project

   ```
   <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-api-client-assembly</artifactId>
   <version>last version </version>
   </dependency>
   ```

I do this on EJB project using netbeans and glassfish server, so I download the jar file of the last version com.google.api-client add it on Netbeans Libraries and glassfish libraries, then I compile the project and restart glassfish.